# numpy concatenate of empty with non empty arrays yields in float

Tags: numpy

I just found that concatenating an empty array with a non-empty array yielded in a one value array containing the non-empty array but changed to a float.
for example:

```
import numpy as np
np.concatenate([1], [1])
array([1, 1])
```

but

```
np.concatenate([], [1])
array([1.])
```

this works the same with np.hstack

Answer (score 0):

By default, the empty array in the code

```
np.concatenate([], [1])
```

is initialized with `dtype=float`, and concatenate casts the second `int` array to `float`.

Now, it's worth asking if it ever happens that you use concatenate on empty arrays. Clearly, you never write code like

```
a=array([1,2,3])#int array
b=np.concatenate([], a)
```

One case scenario where it may happens follows:

```
a=array([1,2,3])#int array
b=concatenate((a[:j],a)) #usually j!=0 here
```

Then for some reasons the code is run with `j=0`. it is true that `a[:0]` is empty, but it still retains the `dtype=int` and the result of concatenate is an array of integer anyway, as you expected.

So I would say that yes, your example shows somehow an unexpected behaviour at first sight, but it's quite harmless.